# "SSL input filter read failed" Apache and 443

Tags: apache, ssl, https

I have a little problem with my apache conf. When I read the error log, here is what I can see:

```
[client xxx.xxx.xx.xx] AH01964: Connection to child 1 established (server www.mywebsite.com:443)
[client xxx.xxx.xx.xx] AH01964: Connection to child 6 established (server www.mywebsite.com:443)
[client xxx.xxx.xx.xx] AH01964: Connection to child 10 established (server www.mywebsite.com:443)
[client xxx.xxx.xx.xx] AH01964: Connection to child 15 established (server www.mywebsite.com:443)
[client xxx.xxx.xx.xx] AH01964: Connection to child 18 established (server www.mywebsite.com:443)
(70014)End of file found: [client xxx.xxx.xx.xx] AH01991: SSL input filter read failed.
(70014)End of file found: [client xxx.xxx.xx.xx] AH01991: SSL input filter read failed.
(70014)End of file found: [client xxx.xxx.xx.xx] AH01991: SSL input filter read failed.
(70014)End of file found: [client xxx.xxx.xx.xx] AH01991: SSL input filter read failed.
(70014)End of file found: [client xxx.xxx.xx.xx] AH01991: SSL input filter read failed.
```

And sometimes, this one:

```
 (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client xxx.xxx.xx.xx] AH01991: SSL input filter read failed.
```

I don't know actually ... so my website is full HTTP, except two page in HTTPS. So here is my virtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mywebsite.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.mywebsite.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias img.mywebsite.com
    ServerAdmin xxx
    DocumentRoot /home/mywebsite/www/public
    <Directory /home/mywebsite/www/>
        Options Indexes Multiviews FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        ErrorDocument 403 http://www.google.com/
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/mywebsite/www/public/resource/private/>
        Require all denied
        ErrorDocument 403 http://www.mywebsite.com/
    </Directory>
    <Location "/robots.txt">
            Require all granted
    </Location>

    LogLevel info
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mywebsite_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mywebsite_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.mywebsite.com
        DocumentRoot /home/mywebsite/www/public
            <Directory /home/mywebsite/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymlinks Multiviews
                AllowOverride all
                Require all granted
            </Directory>
        LogLevel info
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mywebsite_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mywebsite_access.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile ./mywebsite.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile ./mywebsite.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile ./intermediate.crt
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

So, where I've done a mistake? I can't find it out ... Can you help me?

thank :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read that Apache doesn't support SSL on name-based virtual host, only on IP based Virtual Hosts. So I changed it:

```
  <VirtualHost *:443>
```

by:

```
  <VirtualHost 192.168.1.1:443>
```

For now, it seems to work, I don't know if it's the good solution, but I don't have any error ...